# Have Vim remember previous line and column position

Tags: linux, vim

How would I have Vim remember and position the cursor at the previous line position and column position when a specific file is reloaded? Right now I am able to have vim remember the line position, but vim starts at the beginning of the line instead of the previous column position.

Comment: Does not the `\`\`` works for you?

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`:mkview`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#:mkview) to save the cursor position (folds, etc.) when you close a file. Then use [`:loadview`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#:loadview) next time you use the file.

To make this automatic, add these lines in your vimrc:

```
autocmd BufWinLeave *.* mkview
autocmd BufWinEnter *.* silent loadview
```

You may also find the [`restore_view.vim`](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4021) plugin useful.